# How to Get user data like email id who are login with facebook into my app?

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Hai I am using login with facebook option to my monotouch app, i want to access the **email** id's of those users,  is it possible?

Please anyone help me....
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing the Facebook Auth part of your code, you need to request `email` in your `scope`. Once the user has granted you that, you can query for their email address via this endpoint - https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token=TOKEN .

There's a more detailed explanation of the FB login flow on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/).